# HTML, CSS: Mi header arruina todo lo demas del body

Tags: html, css

Vi un tutorial sobre como añadir un menu desplegable (no tenia ni idea como), lo añadi, y funciona bien solo que arruina todo lo demas, hace que el fondo y todo lo demas se centre y no llena toda la pantalla:

```css
/* Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Point Free";
    src: url("fonts/pointfree.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Simple Type";
    src: url("fonts/Simpletype.ttf");
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
}
.container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    line-height: 65px;
}
.menu{
    float: right;
    line-height: 65px;
}
.menu ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.menu a:hover{
    background: #ec529f;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu .submenu{
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
}
.menu .submenu li a{
    line-height: 50px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover + ul, .menu .submenu:hover{
    display: block;
}



#firstPartOfBody {
    background: url("fondo-minimalista2.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#secondPartOfBody {
    background: url("fondo-minimalista-parte-2.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#title {
    font-family: "Simple Type";
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;

    cursor: default;
}

#title2 {
    font-family: "Point Free";
    font-size: 70px;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #ff4da6;

    cursor: default;
}

#subtitle {
    font-family: "Point Free";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;

    cursor: default;
}

#firstParagraph {
    font-family: "Point Free";
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;

    cursor: default;
}

#firstParagraph:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}

#separator {
    font-family: "Point Free";
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;

    cursor: default;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    background: rgb(49, 49, 49);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ec529f;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#aplicationTitle {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 65px;
    margin-left: 100px;

    cursor: default;
}

#description {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 180px;

    cursor: default;
}

.useButton {
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 650px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid #ec529f;
    background-color: #000;

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EasyHub</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1 style='font-family: "Simple Type";'>EasyHub</h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Aplicaciones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">¿Por que EasyHub?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <div id="firstPartOfBody">
            <br><br>
            <h1 id="title">EasyHub</h1>
            <br>
            <h3 id="subtitle">Tu hub de herramientas faciles</h3>
            <!-- <audio src="bgmusic.mp3" loop="1000000" autoplay="true" volume=20></audio> -->
            <!-- QUITAR EL COMENTARIO DEL AUDIO LUEGO -->
            <br><br><br><br><br>
            <p id="firstParagraph">
                EasyHub es un hogar de herramientas simples y <br>
                faciles de usar en el momento, cuenta con mas de<br>
                5 herramientas y que cada vez se suman mas y mas<br>
            </p>
            <p id="separator"><s>ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ</s></p>
            <p id="firstParagraph">
                Disfruta de herramientas sin costo, gratuitas<br>
                y utiles para tu dia a dia ¡Estamos las 24 horas<br>
                listos para ayudar!
            </p>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div id="secondPartOfBody">
            <br><br><br>
            <h3 id="title2"><s>ㅤ</s> Aplicaciones <s>ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ</s></h3>
            <br><br>
            <h1 id="aplicationTitle" style="color: #ec529f;">● FreeWrite</h1>
            <br>
            <p id="description">
                Una amplia y gran herramienta libre<br>
                para escribir todo lo que quieras,<br>
                la Caja de Arena de la Escritura.
            </p>
            <input class="useButton" id="freeWriteButton" type="button" value="USAR AHORA">
            <br><br><br><br><br>


            <h1 id="aplicationTitle" style="color: #ec529f;">● Calculadora</h1>
            <br>
            <p id="description">
                Una simple y basica calculadora facil<br> 
                de usar y confunciones utiles para usar<br>
                en tu dia a dia
            </p>
            <input class="useButton" id="calculatorButton" type="button" value="USAR AHORA">
            <br><br><br><br><br><br>
            

            <h1 id="aplicationTitle" style="color: #ec529f;">● Cara o Cruz</h1>
            <br>
            <p id="description">
                El clasico juego de cara o cruz,<br>
                solo hay 2 posibilidades, ¡deja que<br>
                la suerte elija todo por ti!
            </p>
            <input class="useButton" id="faceOrCrossButton" type="button" value="USAR AHORA">
            <br><br><br><br><br>


            <h1 id="aplicationTitle" style="color: #ec529f;">● Color Picker</h1>
            <br>
            <p id="description">
                Encuentra el color que necesitas para<br>
                tu proximo proyecto facil y rapido
            </p>
            <input class="useButton" id="colorPickerButton" type="button" value="USAR AHORA">
            <br><br><br><br><br>


            <h1 id="aplicationTitle" style="color: #ec529f;">● Mora (Asistente Virtual)</h1>
            <br>
            <p id="description">
                Tu compañera web, existe y siempre<br>
                esta lista para ayudar o entretener
            </p>
            <input class="useButton" id="virtualAssistentButton" type="button" value="USAR AHORA">
            <br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y asi es como se ve (pongo la imagen porque no puedo incluir la imagen del fondo ni las fuentes)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no tiene que verse asi, tiene que el fondo cubrir toda la pantalla y que los textos se acomoden a la pantalla

Disculpen si no se dar muchos detalles, es que no se como solucionarlo y no se me ocurre como

Espero y me ayuden :D

Saludos.

Comment: Comenta o elimina esta línea dentro de la clase `container` de tu CSS:  `max-width: 1100px;`  Y si aun no te concence haz lo mismo con la siguiente que pone `margin: auto;` y ya nos diras si con eso se arregla

Comment: @Skeletoos57 comenta los Css del container y cambialo por container-fuild si usas bootstrap es la clase para que te vaia el contenedor de punta a punta. El container normal te pone unos margenes. Aunque en el codigo no lo veo que lo uses pero. Otra solucion es ponerle un **min-width:100vw;**

Comment: @masterguru Gracias! Ya funciona perfectamente

Comment: De nada! Me alegro :-)

Answer (score 1):

La solucion era quitar las lineas `max-width: 1100px;` y `margin: auto;` en el `.container`.

Gracias a los comentarios por su ayuda :)